# java - Calling a PL/SQL Stored Procedure With Arrays

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql, associative-array

I have a PL/SQL stored procedure similar to the following that I need to call in Java:

```
TYPE AssocArrayVarchar20_t   is table of VARCHAR2(20)   index by BINARY_INTEGER
TYPE AssocArrayVarchar4100_t is table of VARCHAR2(4100) index by BINARY_INTEGER
TYPE AssocArrayNumber_t      is table of NUMBER         index by BINARY_INTEGER

PROCEDURE DATA_WRITE( I_NAME IN AssocArrayVarchar20_t,
                      I_NUM  IN AssocArrayNumber_t,
                      I_NOTE IN AssocArrayVarchar4100_t)
    // Do Stuff
END DATA_WRITE;
```

I tried the following in Java:

```
CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall("begin DATA_WRITE(?, ?, ?); end;");
stmt.setArray(0, conn.createArrayOf("VARCHAR", new String[]{ name }));
stmt.setArray(1, conn.createArrayOf("NUMBER", new Integer[]{ num }));
stmt.setArray(2, conn.createArrayOf("VARCHAR2", new String[]{ notes }));
stmet.execute;
```

When I do this I get a `SQLException: Unsupported Feature"` on the `createArrayOf()` method. I've also tried `setObject()` and inside of `createArrayOf`: `"varchar"`, `"AssocArrayVarchar20_t"`, `"varchar_t"`. Nothing seems to change that outcome.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I can't seem to get it to work.

UPDATE: Success!

```
OracleCallableStatement pStmt = (OracleCallableStatement) conn.prepareCall("begin DATA_WRITE(?, ?, ?); end;");
pStmt.setPlsqlIndexTable(1, new String[]{ name }, 1, 1, OracleTypes.VARCHAR, 20);
pStmt.setPlsqlIndexTable(2, new Integer[]{ num }, 1, 1, OracleTypes.NUMBER, 0);
pStmt.setPlsqlIndexTable(3, new String[]{ notes }, 1, 1, OracleTypes.VARCHAR, 4100);
pStmt.execute();
```

Comment: You might find this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/7878735/272735 useful. Please also show us the definitions of the arrays (e.g. `AssocArrayVarchar20_t`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`createArrayOf` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#createArrayOf-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-) was introduced in Java 1.6, but to the best of my knowledge it doesn't handle Oracle's PL/SQL associative arrays.  If you have the Oracle JDBC driver, then you have access to the `oracle.sql` classes.

You should be able to downcast the `CallableStatement` to an `OracleCallableStatement`.  From there you can call [the `setPlsqlIndexTable` method](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OraclePreparedStatement.html#setPlsqlIndexTable_int__java_lang_Object__int__int__int__int_) and you should be able to pass in a Java array.

> Binds a PL/SQL index-by table parameter in the IN parameter mode.

Comment: I'm getting "wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'DATA_WRITE'" but I have all 3 inputs and I think they're the right types. See code above. The stored procedure does use VARCHAR2 maybe that's the problem? But there is no `OracleTypes.VARCHAR2`.

Comment: Scratch that last comment, I misspelled my Stored Proc

Answer (score 3):

Here is an official guide reference to pass Arrays in case you need to pass arrays and not tables: [oracle guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/oraarr.htm#JJDBC28606)

> Oracle JDBC does not support the JDBC 4.0 method createArrayOf method
>   of java.sql.Connection interface. This method only allows anonymous
>   array types, while all Oracle array types are named. Use the Oracle
>   specific method oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection.createARRAY instead.
>
> **Passing an Array to a Prepared Statement**
>
> Pass an array to a prepared statement as follows.
>
> Note: you can use arrays as either IN or OUT bind variables. Define
>   the array that you want to pass to the prepared statement as an
>   oracle.sql.ARRAY object.
>
> `ARRAY array = oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection.createARRAY(sql_type_name,`
>   elements); sql_type_name is a Java string specifying the user-defined
>   SQL type name of the array and elements is a java.lang.Object
>   containing a Java array of the elements.
>
> Create a java.sql.PreparedStatement object containing the SQL
>   statement to be run.
>
> Cast your prepared statement to OraclePreparedStatement, and use
>   setARRAY to pass the array to the prepared statement.
>
> `(OraclePreparedStatement)stmt.setARRAY(parameterIndex, array);`
>   parameterIndex is the parameter index and array is the
>   oracle.sql.ARRAY object you constructed previously.
>
> Run the prepared statement.

Note: by the

```
ARRAY array = oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection.createARRAY(sql_type_name, elements);
```

They mean:

```
java.sql.Connection connection = ...
oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection oracleConnection = connection.unwrap(OracleConnection.class);
ARRAY array = oracleConnection.createARRAY(sql_type_name, elements);
```

Comment: I have used createARRAY() also to pass a Java array to a PL/SQL stored procedure that has a PL/SQL table as input parameter.  It works.  Also note that Oracle ARRAY class implements the standard java.sql.Array interface so you can write `Array array = oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection.createARRAY(sql_type_name, elements);` and the only non-standard object you have to use is OracleConnection.