# Oracle jdbc "createArray" throws "Unsupported feature" exception while trying to pass array to prepared statement

Tags: oracle, scala, jdbc

I am trying to pass an array to my prepared statement by doing ***createArrayOf***

```scala
val array = Array("1165006001","1165006002")
val sqlArray = con.createArrayOf("VARCHAR",array) // getting the exception here 
val prep = con.prepareStatement("select * from SOA_WEB_USER.VOPEX where CMF_PPK_NBR in (?)")
prep.setArray(1,sqlArray)
    
val rs = prep.executeQuery()
while (rs.next()) {
  println(rs.getObject(1))
}
```

But createArrayOf method throws an error saying

```
Exception  thread "main" java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException:Unsupported feature   
at Oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.createArrayOf(PhysicalConnection.java:8707)
at com.testpackage.Main$.main(Main.scala:109)
at com.testpackage.Main.main(Main.scala)    
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

I am using the ojdbc7.jar for the jdbc connection.
Is there anything I can do differently to pass the array to the prepared statement?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not going to answer the question you've asked ("how can I pass the array to the prepared statement"), because even if you could figure out how to pass the array, your code would quite probably still not work.

The problem is that with JDBC you can't pass an array of two values `("1165006001","1165006002")`into the query

```
select * from SOA_WEB_USER.VOPEX where CMF_PPK_NBR in (?)
```

and expect it to be interpreted by the database as

```
select * from SOA_WEB_USER.VOPEX where CMF_PPK_NBR in ('1165006001','1165006002')
```

as it seems to me you want it to.

If you could pass the array in, the query would return all rows for which the column `CMF_PPK_NBR` contained a nested table with those two values.  Oracle would interpret the array as one value, rather than two.  I'm guessing that column has type either `VARCHAR2`, and so you'd only end up with a type error as Oracle tries to compare an array of strings to a single string.

If you want to pass multiple values in an `IN` clause, then the simplest way is to build up a SQL string with a number of `?` marks, and set values for the parameters individually.  In other words, for the example above, the SQL string for two parameters would be

```
select * from SOA_WEB_USER.VOPEX where CMF_PPK_NBR in (?, ?)
```

and you would have two calls to `prep.setString(...)`, one for each array element.  Similarly, if there were, say, 5 items in the array, you'd build a SQL string with 5 `?` marks, and call `prep.setString(...)` 5 times, and so on.

Comment: This answer is misleading as there are [ways to pass arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34699771/1509264) - You can create a collection with `CREATE TYPE StringList IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(20)` then `SELECT * FROM DUAL WHERE DUMMY MEMBER OF ?` you can pass in an array of strings as a `StringList` type using the `oracle.sql.ARRAY` java class and `oracle.jdbc.OracleCallableStatement.setARRAYAtName( String, ARRAY )` method. If you want to use the `IN` operator then you can use a table collection expression: `SELECT * FROM DUAL WHERE DUMMY IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(?))`.

Comment: @MT0: I'm not saying there aren't ways to pass arrays, I'm only saying the above approach is the simplest.  Besides, what if the questioner lacks the permission to create types in the database?

Comment: Does anyone have the example of that iteration, based on the size of the array?

Answer (score 14):

Oracle Database JDBC drivers do not support Connection.createArrayOf because the Oracle Database does not support anonymous array types. A type ARRAY OF FOO is an anonymous type. The array type has no name though the base type does. Oracle Database does not support anonymous array types. You have to define a named type

```
TYPE ARRAY_OF_FOO IS TABLE OF FOO;
```

You can then create an Array by calling

```
oracleConnection.createOracleArray("ARRAY_OF_FOO", elements);
```

---

**Edit**: As @gouessej mentioned in the comments, you can even use a [built-in](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76571542/458157) type in the [Oracle Database Data Cartridge](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/addci/introduction-to-data-cartridges.html) extension. It gets even simpler:

```scala
val sqlArray = oracleConnection.createOracleArray("SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST", Array("1165006001","1165006002"))
val prep = oracleConnection.prepareStatement("select * from SOA_WEB_USER.VOPEX where CMF_PPK_NBR in (select * from TABLE(?))")
prep.setArray(1, sqlArray)

val rs = prep.executeQuery()
while (rs.next()) {
  println(rs.getObject(1))
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I really do not understand how can be "I am not going to answer the question you've asked" the accepted answer. It's fine to provide alternative better solution or criticese other problems, but I really think that the the actual question should be answered, as it's painful to find actual question for problem you are actually facing only to find "I am not going to answer the question you've asked". Thanks again for providing actual anwer, you helped me a lot.

Comment: Probably too late to answer but cant use accepted answer so thats how I solved it:
***
String SQL = "Select * from users where name in (%s)" ;
String name =  String.join(",", namesList);
con.prepareStatement(String.format(SQL, name));
***

Comment: You can use a build-in type when it fits into your need like in my example, it's simpler: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76571542/458157

Answer (score 6):

There's no completely nice way to do that, but still two reasonable ways exist.

#### Use a hand-crafted `in (?,...)` clause.

The [solution is explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3107059/223424). The idea is to add as many `?`s as threre are array elements, and bind each item individually. This gives you safety of mind because values will be properly translated, escaped, etc.

This sort of defeats the purpose of preparing a statement, unless your arrays are normally the same size.

You can also run out of the allowed query length if you have great many items in the array.

#### Use a cast and pass the array as a string.

The solution (for PL/SQL) is [explained here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:210612357425), but applies to general SQL statements. It boils down to using a clause like

```
...in (select cast(in_list(?) as some_table_type) from dual)
```

The parameter here is passed as `varchar2`, like `"1, 2, 3"`, is parsed as an in-memory table, and is selected from, all inside the `in` clause.

This allows you to have a query of a fixed length, and possibly efficiently reuse the prepared statement. It also allows you to pass great many items in the array.

It, OTOH, *requires you to concatenate and pass the data as a string,* which can potentially lead to an *SQL injection.* I'd still suppose it to be safe if your array values are numeric.