# Can I pass a list of String in the IN clause of sql statement(Oracle) using Java code

Tags: java, sql, oracle12c, nested-table, oracle-type

Can I pass a list of String in the IN clause of sql statement(Oracle 12c) using Java code.

My code is given below:

```
    Connection con= abc.getConnection();
    OracleConnection oracleConnection = null;
    OraclePreparedStatement ops=null;
    if (con.isWrapperFor(OracleConnection.class)){
           oracleConnection= con.unwrap(OracleConnection.class);  
        }else{
           // recover, not an oracle connection
        }
    PreparedStatement ps=oracleConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
    if (ps.isWrapperFor(OraclePreparedStatement.class)){
        ops= ps.unwrap(OraclePreparedStatement.class);  
        }else{
           // recover, not an oracle connection
        }
    List<String >Ids=new ArrayList<String>();
    Ids.add("12345");
    Ids.add("12346");
    java.sql.Array array1 = oracleConnection.createOracleArray("MY_NESTED_TABLE", Ids.toArray());
    ops.setArray(1, array1 );
    ResultSet rSet= ops.executeQuery();
```

I have defined my Oracle Nested Table as:

create or replace `TYPE MY_NESTED_TABLE AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(8 BYTE);`

And the sql queries I tried to execute are:

1. `SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE where MY_COLUMN IN (select column_value v from table(?))`
2. `SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE where MY_COLUMN IN (select column_value v from table(cast(? AS MY_NESTED_TABLE)))`

There is no exception, just that I get no data in resultset.
I have seen people using this code working with PL/SQL. Should it work with a SQL statement as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tested your approach and it is working fine. Please check if your mapping is correct and data is present in database.

**Yes, you can use oracle arrays in sql statement.**

[How to create an oracle.sql.ARRAY object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878735/how-to-create-an-oracle-sql-array-object)