# Pass an array of numbers (TABLE OF NUMBER) Input Param to a Stored Proc call in SpringJDBC

Tags: spring, stored-procedures, spring-jdbc

In SpringJDBC I need to call a SP whose parameter is a `TABLE OF NUMBER` type, i.e. an array of numbers.

```
  PROCEDURE MY_SP(              PARAM1                IN TABLE OF NUMBER,
                                PARAM2                IN NUMBER,
```

An input of `[1]` (1-element integer array) is valid.  But when I try to pass it in directly per the declaration of this param as `OracleTypes.ARRAY`

```
    declareParameter(new SqlParameter("PARAM1", OracleTypes.ARRAY));
```

I get

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation: [Ljava.lang.Integer;@16a25973
    at oracle.sql.ARRAY.toARRAY(ARRAY.java:308)
```

There's an [old example here](https://mytechrepo.wordpress.com/tag/how-to-pass-table-of-number-to-plsql-function-from-java/) which uses the deprecated `ArrayDescriptor` and builds a SQL `Array`. That must be from an older SpringJDBC. `ArrayDescriptor` is deprecated, and also I don't have access to `connection`. I'm using the modern SpringJDBC approach of implementing the `StoredProcedure` interface (with `compile()`)which doesn't expose a `connection`. Any thoughts?

```
@Component
public class MySP extends StoredProcedure {
    
    private RowMapper<List<Object>> rowMapper = new MyMapper();
    
    public MySP(@Autowired DataSource dataSource) {
        super(dataSource, "MYPACKAGE.MY_SP");

        declareParameter(new SqlParameter("PARAM1", OracleTypes.ARRAY));
        //...
        compile();
   }

   public String callSP(Integer[] intArray) {
        //intArray contains a 1-element integer array, e.g. [1]
        Map<String, Object> inputParameters = new HashMap<>();
        inputParameters.put("PARAM1", intArray);

        Map<String, Object> output = super.execute(inputParameters);
        // Process results...
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a custom Array type defined in Oracle as e.g. below:

```
create or replace TYPE   "REF_TYPE_ARRAY"  IS TABLE OF NUMBER
```

Then in Java's `StoredProcedure` implementation you can do the following: you (1) unwrap the OracleConnection and then (2) do `createOracleArray`.

```
@Component
public class MyStoredProcedure extends StoredProcedure {

    public MyStoredProcedure(@Autowired DataSource dataSource) {
        super(dataSource, "MY_PKG.MY_STORED_PROC"); // Name

        declareParameter(new SqlParameter("itemIds", OracleTypes.ARRAY, "REF_TYPE_ARRAY"));
        // etc. other parameters

}

public void execute(ParamObject paramObject) throws Exception{
    Map<String, Object> inputParameters = new HashMap<>();
    
    OracleConnection oracleConnection = getJdbcTemplate().getDataSource().getConnection().unwrap(OracleConnection.class);
    Array array = oracleConnection.createOracleArray("REF_TYPE_ARRAY", referralTypeId);
    
    inputParameters.put("itemIds", array); 
    // etc. other params
```

This works, but we ran into some occasional leaked connections and JDBC issues with this approach. We had to re-write our SP as a simple `CallableStatement` where you specify the array directly as

```
private static final String SQL = 
" {call MY_PKG.MY_SP(REF_TYPE_ARRAY(?),?,?) } ";

try(Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection(); CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall(SQL)) {
                    
        cs.setString(1, itemIds);
        //etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JdbcTemplate to access the connection and perform your operations. Create your array as follows: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76571542/7565792

```
    import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    
    // ...
    
    // Access the connection using JdbcTemplate
    Connection connection = jdbcTemplate.execute(con -> {
        // Here, you have access to the connection object.
        //create your array like mentioned in the link above: 
        return con;
    });
    connection.close();
```

Comment: Yes, the answer is to unwrap the OracleConnection and then createOracleArray. I'll post the complete answer.