# Mapping java type string[] to oracle type

Tags: java, oracle, type-conversion

There's some java class, loaded to Oracle database (version 11g), and pl/sql function-wrapper:

```
create or replace function getDataFromJava( in_uListOfSms  in tStringArray )
return tStringArray    
as language java name 'JavaClass.getSms( java.lang.String[]) return java.lang.String[]';
```

as you can see from example I try to match java datatype 'java.lang.String[]' to Oracle datatype:

```
create or replace type tStringArray as table of varchar2(4000);
```

and then when I run this code:

```
declare
  in_array  tStringArray := tStringArray();    
  out_array tStringArray := tStringArray();    
begin    

  in_array.EXTEND;    
  in_array(1) := '1';    
  in_array.EXTEND;    
  in_array(2) := '2';    
  in_array.EXTEND;    
  in_array(3) := '3';    

    out_array := getDataFromJava( in_array );    

      for i in 1..3    
      loop    
        dbms_output.put_line(out_array(i));    
      end loop;    
end;
```

as a result I get error:

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes expected a java type at argument position 2 to which some Oracle value can be converted got something else
```

Comment: I think you are looking this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7872688/how-to-return-an-array-from-java-to-pl-sql

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've done this! The key mistake in my approach was impression that java datatype String[] should match with oracle dstatape based on "table of varchar2". That's wrong. If you have to do in/out parameters as array of strins/numbers/dates you should use oracle.sql.ARRAY datatype.
Here small example of this approach:

1. Create oracle datatype:

   CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE tFilesList AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(2000);
2. Create method which returns oracle.sql.ARRAY:

   create or replace and compile java source named "DirInfo" as

> ```
> import java.io.File;    
> import java.sql.*;    
> import oracle.sql.*;    
> import oracle.jdbc.*;    
>
> public class DirInfo {    
>
>   public static oracle.sql.ARRAY getFilesList (String dirName) throws java.sql.SQLException {    
>
>       Connection orclConnection = new OracleDriver().defaultConnection();    
>
>       ArrayDescriptor arrayDesc = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor ("TFILESLIST", orclConnection);    
>
>       File filesDir = new File (dirName);    
>
>       String[] filesList = filesDir.list();    
>
>       ARRAY dirArray = new ARRAY(arrayDesc, orclConnection, filesList);    
>
>       return dirArray;    
>   }
> }
> ```

3. Create pl/sql function-wrapper:

   create or replace function getDirList (dirName in varchar2)
   return tFilesList
   as
   language java name 'DirInfo.getFilesList(java.lang.String) return
   oracle.sql.ARRAY';
4. Test:

> ```
>  declare    
>        myDdir tFilesList;    
>     begin    
>       myDdir := getDirList ('C:\Program Files');    
>         for i in 1..myDdir.COUNT    
>         loop    
>           dbms_output.put_line(myDdir(i));    
>         end loop;    
>     end;
> ```