# How to map TYPE TABLE OF VARCHAR2 in Spring JPA with @Procedure annotation?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Currently, I am trying to use a store procedure (SP) that was created in Oracle, from Spring Data, with JPA and the annotation @Procedure.

It seems easy, but the procedure has a Table type parameter (cause it is an array), and as soon as I execute the method in the repository I am getting the following error message:

> ```
> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SP_NAME'
> ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
> PL/SQL: Statement ignored
> ```

The SP_NAME (store procedure name) has the following declaration:

```
PROCEDURE SP_NAME(mv_name IN MVIEWS_ARRAYS) as ...... more code
```

Like you can see in the declaration SP, it is making reference to MVIEWS_ARRAYS type, that is declared like a **TYPE**, like follows:

```
create or replace TYPE   MVIEWS_ARRAYS IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (1000);
```

When I try to use the SP from the Oracle client, with the following code, it is working fine:

```
DECLARE    
mv_name MVIEWS_ARRAYS := MVIEWS_ARRAYS ('1', 'Two', 'Something else');   
BEGIN     
    SP_NAME(mv_name);  
END;
```

However when I try to call the SP from the JAVA, with the following code like an example of a repository;

```
@Repository
public interface InterfaceRepositoryExample  extends JpaRepository<SomeEntity, Integer>{
    
    @Async
    @Procedure("SP_NAME")
    public void spName(String[] mvName);
    
}
```

I am getting the error in the parameter types (the error that is above).

I have searched about this, but I have not had luck, there are not a type relation between Table type in Oracle and some primitive or wrapper type in Java, MoreOver, I have found lots post without response and also some codes to create dynamic objects from Java, but I do not know if this is I am searching.

Does someone have some idea about how I can solve this mistake?.

Regards.

EDITED:

I have tried to do it in different ways, but I was not able to use the SP.

1.- Using Array instead String[], (Ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/old-docs/2.0.0.M1/reference/html/orcl.datatypes.html, 6.2 epigraph)

```
   @Repository
    public interface InterfaceRepositoryExample  extends JpaRepository<SomeEntity, Integer>{
        
        @Async
        @Procedure("SP_NAME")
        public void spName(Array mvName);
        
    }
```

from the service I am converting String[] to Array:

```
java.sql.Array sqlArray = dataSource.getConnection().unwrap(OracleConnection.class).createOracleArray("MVIEWS_ARRAYS ", data);
```

But I am getting the error message:

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Type
> cannot be null; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type cannot be null

2.- With CallableStatement:

```
public void useSP(Array array) throws SQLException {
    CallableStatement proc = null;
    String sql = "{ call SP_NAME(?) }";
    try{
      proc = dataSource.getConnection().unwrap(OracleConnection.class).prepareCall(sql);
      proc.setArray(1, array);
      proc.execute();
    }finally{
      proc.close();
    }
}
```

from the service I am converting String[] to Array:

```
java.sql.Array sqlArray = dataSource.getConnection().unwrap(OracleConnection.class).createOracleArray("MVIEWS_ARRAYS ", data);
useSP(sqlArray);
```

But I am getting the error message:

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00306: wrong
> number or types of arguments in call to 'SP_NAME' ORA-06550: line 1,
> column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try approach to use JPA to execute statement instead. Then pass your param as Oracle.Array as reference here: [How to map TYPE TABLE OF VARCHAR2(5) in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28606108/how-to-map-type-table-of-varchar25-in-java)